# Typed array of generic classes

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

Consider the following simplified protocol/class hierarchy

```
protocol P {
}

class A: P {
}

class B: P {
}

class C<T: P> {
}
```

I want to create a typed array of instances of the class `C`. The automatic type inference does not seem to work, however. When I do

```
let objs = [C<A>(), C<B>()]
let obj = objs[0]
```

`objs` and `obj` are of type `[AnyObject]` and `AnyObject`, respectively. I would have expected something like

```
let objs:[C<P>] = [C<A>(), C<B>()]
```

to work but it doesn't compile with the error

```
Using 'P' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'P' is not supported
```

Omitting the generic type altogether like so

```
let objs:[C] = [C<A>(), C<B>()]
```

produces a different error on compilation

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray' to specified type '[C]'
```

Is there any way I could create an array of `C` instances with a type more specific than `[AnyObject]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider following code:

```
// DOES NOT WORK!!

protocol P {
    var name: String { get }
}

class A: P {
    var name = "A"
}

class B: P {
    var name = "B"
}

class C<T: P> {
    var val: T
    init(val: T) {
        self.val = val
    }
}

let objs: [C<P>] = [ C<A>(A()) ]

let firstObj: C<P> = obj[0]
firstObj.val = B()
```

In this case, `firstObj` is actually a `C<A>` instance. But `firstObj.val` must accept `B()` because `firstObj.val` is constrained to `P` and `B` conforms to `P`. This is illegal you know. That is why you cannot cast `C<A>` as `C<P>`

To workaround this, for example, you can create some wrapper around the `C`:

```
protocol P {
    var name: String { get }
}

class A: P {
    var name = "A"
}

class B: P {
    var name = "B"
}

class C<T: P> {
    var val: T
    init(_ val: T) {
        self.val = val
    }
}

/// Type erasing wrapper around C that has accessor for `C.val`
struct AnyC {

    let _val: () -> P
    var val: P { return _val() }

    init<T>(_ c: C<T>) {
        _val = { return c.val }
    }
}

let objs:[AnyC] = [
    AnyC( C<A>(A()) ),
    AnyC( C<B>(B()) ),
]
objs[0].val.name // -> "A"
objs[1].val.name // -> "B"
```

Comment: It's a good point that the assignment would be illegal in that particular example. On the other hand, `val` could also be a `let` constant and you could just be calling protocol methods on it which would be perfectly valid. But it's probably not possible to deny the former case and support the latter which is why you'd have to use a wrapper. Thanks for the input! :)

Comment: You might want to see [this dev forum topic](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1103057) as well.